# Openshift NodeJS files not updated after git push

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

I am trying to push fix of **package.json** to my node app on openshift, but even the git says that openshift is **up-to-date**, it isn't. When I ssh to **app-root/repo** content I see that **package.json** is still outdated. It doesn't contains **scripts:{start:"node server.js"}** neither **main:"server.js"**.

I was trying to git pull via ssh, but I wasn't able to found git repository

```
git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)
```

rhc commands does not work

```
rhc app restart -a sjs
Stopping Node.js application...
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/************/nodejs
```

same output for **rhc stop**

**I have read many similar questions in here, but no answer fits my situtation.**

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @user2928231 I did make new nodeJS project, merged it with my old one, and then it start working... dont know what was the real problem, because it was solved by auto merge part, I didnt notice anything important while manual merge. :/

Comment: ... I recalled that I also merged `scripts:{start:"node server.js"}` and `main:"server.js".` into package.json so maybe that made a difference, or maybe it was somewhere inside auto merge, I am not sure.